# Double finite summations with linked indices: verifying intuitions from tabulation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

In handling a separate problem ([see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4786496/1234572)), I've encountered the need to get rid of some double summations where the inner index is linked to the outer one. Having searched for ready-to-use results about double sums and failed, I've rather clumsily deduced the following equivalences from "tabulating" the double summations for small values of $n$:

- $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i}f(j)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)f(i)$
- $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}f(j)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(n-1-i)f(i)$
- $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\left[\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}f(j) \right]=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \left[ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{j(j+1)}{2}\right]f(j) $

Is there a way I can reassure myself these equivalences are reliable? They (kind of) do the job, yet I am unable to back them up with references, and unqualified to provide formal proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we show how to verify the first two identities. The third identity can then be shown similarly.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_n:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^if(j)}
> &=\sum_{0\leq j\leq i\leq n-1}f(j)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(j)\sum_{i=j}^{n-1}1\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(j)\left((n-1)-(j-1)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(j)(n-j)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(i)(n-i)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use just another suitable way to describe the index-region we use for summation.
- In (2) we change the order of summation by exchanging left and right-hand sum.
- In (3) we replace the inner sum by the number of summands.
- In (4) we exchange the index notation $i\leftrightarrow j$.

Now the next identity. We can trace it back to the first identity.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}f(j)}
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}f(j)\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\sum_{j=0}^i f(j)\\
> &=S_{n-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}f(i)(n-1-i)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (5) we note that using $i=0$, the upper index of the inner sum is less than the lower index $j=0$ and therefore the inner sum is empty and the summand with $i=0$ is equal to zero. We can therefore skip $i=0$.

Comment: This is really neat. Thank you!

Comment: @DrEti: You're welcome. :-)